# How to convert a list into a 2d matrix?

Tags: python

I have my data in form of list but for easy access I need them to be in matrix of 11 rows known as `p0-p10` and 4 columns as `a,b,c,d`.

This is my data:

```
[
[0.078125, 0.328125, 0.328125, 0.265625], 
[0.171875, 0.390625, 0.140625, 0.296875], 
[0.109375, 0.015625, 0.015625, 0.859375], 
[0.859375, 0.015625, 0.109375, 0.015625], 
[0.953125, 0.015625, 0.015625, 0.015625], 
[0.015625, 0.015625, 0.234375, 0.734375], 
[0.046875, 0.921875, 0.015625, 0.015625], 
[0.109375, 0.421875, 0.109375, 0.359375], 
[0.140625, 0.484375, 0.359375, 0.015625], 
[0.078125, 0.296875, 0.421875, 0.203125]
]
```

I have tried with `numpy` but it's not working is there any other method?

Comment: NumPy should surely work. I'd advice you to give this another shot. It should be really straightforward

Comment: Your list is already a 2d matrix in Python, only the rows and columns don't have names, they have indices. For example what you want to call `p1.c` is contained in `data[1][2]` which is the second row, third column of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy works

Example:

```
a = [[0.078125, 0.328125, 0.328125, 0.265625], [0.171875, 0.390625, 0.140625, 0.296875], [0.109375, 0.015625, 0.015625, 0.859375], [0.859375, 0.015625, 0.109375, 0.015625], [0.953125, 0.015625, 0.015625, 0.015625], [0.015625, 0.015625, 0.234375, 0.734375], [0.046875, 0.921875, 0.015625, 0.015625], [0.109375, 0.421875, 0.109375, 0.359375], [0.140625, 0.484375, 0.359375, 0.015625], [0.078125, 0.296875, 0.421875, 0.203125]]
a = np.array(a)
print(a.shape)
```

(10,4)

```
a = a.reshape((4,10))
print(a.shape)
```

(4,10)

Comment: if i get my matrix (10,4) how to call a element of matrix individually?

Comment: a[row_number, column namber] - for individual element, example: a[2,3]